# Form not saving data to MySQL database

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I am having trouble recording a single data (deckName) from this form to my MySQL database. I read and tried all the solutions I found over the web, but I cannot get it to work. Doing the MySQL command from the PHPMyAdmin work fine.

I need to save in the deck table of the db (id, name, cards) the values.

Jquery/Ajax script:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){     

        $(document).on('submit','.save',function(){

            var deckName = $('.deck').val();
            console.log(deckName);

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "submit.php",
                data: { "name": deckName},
                success: console.log('worked')

            });
        });
    }); 

</script>
```

Form:

```
<div class="decklist">
    <form method="post" id="decklist">
    <input class="deck" id="deckN" type="text" value="Deck name"/>
    <input class="save" type="submit" value="Save Deck"/>
    </form>
    <div class="list">
        <ul class="d_list">
            <li class='added_card' id='list_0'></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

submit.php:

```
<?php


if(isset($_POST["name"])&& strlen($_POST["name"])>0){

    $deckName = $_POST["name"];
    $cards = 0;

    echo $deckName;

    $conn = new mysqli("localhost:8080","root","","ken");
    if($conn -> connect_errno){
        die("Failed to connect: (". $conn->connect_errno. ")".$conn->connect_error);
    }

    $insert = $conn->query ("INSERT INTO `deck` (deck, cards) VALUES ($deckName, $cards)");

    if ($insert){
        echo 'Successfully saved '. $deckName;
        $conn -> close();
    }

}

?>
```

Also once I hit Save Deck for submit, the div get refreshed while I assume it shouldn't with ajax.

I tried using click instead of submit, and the console.log returned everything correctly from the ajax function and the div wasn't refreshing every time, but with submit logs don't show up anymore in console.
I don't get anything from the echo in submit.php, never.

Comment: replace $(document).on('submit','.save',function(){  by $(document).on('submit','.save',function(e){ e.preventDefault;

Comment: I keep trying everything, but still I didn't find any solution to this problem. Stuck here from days now

Comment: Do you see any error in console ? Can you check if ajax is fired ? Try echo something in php and check if ajax returns that

Comment: Seems like Ajax fires correctly (console.log inside the Ajax call prints correctly) but the php script doesn't fire, ever.

Comment: Try adding print_r($_POST); as first line in php script, and see what ajax returns

Comment: In the console only console.log(deckName) and the console.log('worked') from the success par in Ajax show up. Then the page get reloaded (Navigated to http://localhost:8080/ken/index.php)

Answer (score 2):

Try using `preventDefault;` like so

```
$(document).on('submit','.save',function(e){ 
 e.preventDefault;
```

Hope it solves your problem !

Comment: Tried but it didn't solved the problem unluckily. Thank you anyway.

Comment: also replace success: console.log('worked')  by success: function(){ console.log('worked');}

Comment: I did it, following @RafH answer, but it seems it doesn't help

Comment: The console doesn't show any error except for a couple of missing images, not related to this question

Answer (score 0):

You have to put quotes around string values:

```
"INSERT INTO `deck` (deck, cards) VALUES ('$deckName', $cards)"
```

Comment: It won't help, see the question form is being submitted and page is reloaded.

Comment: It really doesn't change. I tried with double and single quotes before with no luck

Answer (score 0):

how about change js like this:

```
$(".decklist").on("click", ".save", function(){
    $.post("submit.php", { name: deckName }).success(function(){
        console.log('worked');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to bind on the `form` submit event :

```
$(document).ready(function(){    

        $("#decklist").on('submit',function(e){
            e.preventDefault(); 

            var deckName = $('.deck').val();
            console.log(deckName);

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "submit.php",
                data: { "name": deckName},
                success: function(response) { 
                      console.log('worked')
                }

            });
        });
    });
```

Comment: Tried as well but it didn't solved the problem. Thank you anyway.

Answer (score 0):

$(document).ready(function(){

```
    $("#decklist").on('submit',function(e){
        e.preventDefault(); 

        var deckName = $('#deck').val();
        console.log(deckName);

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "submit.php",
            data: { "name": deckName},
            success: function(response) { 
                  console.log('worked')
            }

        });
    });
});
```

it works form me, change $('#deck').val();